# Broken smooth collapse in reactJS material ui after creating Component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-paper-s0c69?file=/src/App.js

Material UI makes smooth collapse.

But, when I put JSX to external component, smooth brakes.
I made code example with smooth collapse and without smooth collapse.

How can I keep Lists in external component and keep smooth collapse?

Answer (score 0):

> But, when I put JSX to external component

Your example does not actually use an external component, you define `Lists` inside of `NestedList` and that function is consequently recreated on every render.

The desired behavior can be achieved by actually having a separate `Lists` component that receives the required props from its parent:

```js
<Lists open={open} handleClick={handleClick} />
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I tried replace my Lists component to your example with props, but nothing changes. Transition makes not smooth.
Please, could you give a full solution?

Comment: did you move `Lists` outside of `NestedList`?